# Call Nextjs API from within Netlify function

Tags: api, next.js, netlify

I got a serverless Netlify function like this:

```
exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({message: "Hello World"})
    };
}
```

When called by this url `<site-name>/.netlify/functions/helloworld`
I do get the message `{"message":"Hello World"}`

I also got a `pages/api/mailingList.js` Nextjs API endpoint:

```
const axios = require('axios');
 
export default async function handler(req, res) {

 //console.log(req.query.mail);

 if (req.method === "PUT") {
   axios
     .put(
       "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts",
       {
         contacts: [{ email: `${req.query.mail}` }],
         list_ids: [process.env.SENDGRID_MAILING_LIST_ID],
       },
       {
         headers: {
           "content-type": "application/json",
           Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY}`,
         },
       }
     )
     .then((result) => {
       res.status(200).send({
         message:
           "Your email has been successfully added to the mailing list. Welcome ",
       });
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       res.status(500).send({
         message:
           "Oups, there was a problem with your subscription, please try again or contact us",
       });
       console.error(err);
     });
  }
}
```

This mailing list API endpoint, do work when using curl from the terminal with PUT as the method:

```
curl -X PUT -d mail=helloworld@gmail.com  https://netlify.app/api/mailingList
```

The API endpoint also work from the URL (`/api/mailingList?mail=helloworld@gmail.com`) when removing the `if (req.method === "PUT") {` part from the `mailingList.js`

*However, I am NOT able to get the API endpoint to be called from within the Netlify function.*

(Preferably the `mailingList` API should be possible to call multiple times with different mailing list IDs from the Netlify function `helloworld.js` based on different logic `/api/mailingList?mail=helloworld@gmail.com&listid=xxx`)

To get the API endpoint to be called at all, from the function, I have tried adding a axios call from the `helloworld.js` to `mailingList.js` like this

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {


    const mail = "helloworld@gmail.com";
    // add to mailinglist
    axios
    .put("/api/mailingList?mail="+mail)
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.status === 200) {
        toast.success(result.data.message);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

}
```

This result in the following error from the browser: `error decoding lambda response: invalid status code returned from lambda: 0`
(I do not get any error msg from the Netlify log, either `helloworld.js` or `mailingList.js`)

Clearly, there is something wrong with how I call the `mailigList.js` from `helloworld.js`. Would greatly appreciate if some one could give me some advice and show me what I am doing wrong.

**How can I call the API endpoint (`mailigList.js`) from within the Netlify function `helloworld.js`?** (Preferably multiple times with different mailing list IDs: `/api/mailingList?mail=helloworld@gmail.com&listid=xxx`)

Comment: Have you tried adding `return` statement in your `axios` call in the API route, e.g. `return axios.put(...).then(...).catch(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in this article: https://travishorn.com/netlify-lambda-functions-from-scratch-1186f61c659e

```
const axios = require('axios');

const mail = "helloworld@gmail.com";


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    axios.put("https://<domain>.netlify.app/api/mailingList?mail="+mail)
      .then((res) => {
        callback(null, {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: res.data.title,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        callback(err);
      });
  };
```